# scraping text inside a element excluding text inside sup tag

Tags: python, css, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, lxml

I need to scrape the text inside  element, but exclude the text inside `<sup>`.

For example:

```
<a> 
    part1 
    <sup> part2 </sup>
    part3
</a>
```

From the above, I need to scrape `part1` and `part2` (not `part3` which is inside `sup`).

I tried css selector with beautifulsoup:

```
soup.select_one('a:not(sup)').get_text(strip=True)
```

but didn't exclude the text inside sup

Answer (score 0):

Use `element.name` method to check the tag name, like:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import element

html = '''
<a> 
    part1 
    <sup> part2 </sup>
    part3
</a>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
print([e.strip() for e in soup.find("a") if e.name != 'sup'])
```

Result:

```
['part1', 'part3']
```